# Does the logback.xml appender element support nested appender-ref element?

Tags: logback, appender, perf4j

I just configured Perf4j on an app which uses Logback for logging. When I tried to setup the `AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender` I nested the appender-ref element which links on the other FileAppender.

But no messages came in to the referenced Appender.

When I was trying to debug it I found that no downstream appenders was set at all!

Then I replaced appender-ref element with a full appender declaration and the downstream appender was set.

I replaced this code

```xml
<appender name="CoalescingStatistics"
              class="org.perf4j.logback.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">

    <param name="TimeSlice" value="10000"/>
    <appender-ref ref="filer" />
</appender>
```

with this:

```xml
<appender name="CoalescingStatistics" class="org.perf4j.logback.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
  <param name="TimeSlice" value="10000" />

  <appender name="filer" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${logs.location}/perfStats.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
          <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
  </appender>
</appender>
```

Does the logback.xml appender element support nested appender-ref elements?

Comment: Can you post your full, non-working `logback.xml`?  The edit to make it work is clear enough.